# Variable expansion in bitbake recipes

Tags: python, linux, bash, yocto

folks.

I've been studying yocto building process and I noticed the usage of the following structure:

`PN = "${@bb.parse.vars_from_file(d.getVar('FILE', False),d)[0] or 'defaultpkgname'}"`

I know that ${} means variable expansion and grep command showed that the function "vars_from_file" is located at bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py.

I would like to understand how this variable expansion works, so I explored bitbake files and found out that:

- oe-init-build-env calls oe-buildenv-internal, and the last one sets PYTHONPATH to bitbake/lib.
- I'm infering that bitbake uses PYTHONPATH to search for the function vars_from_file

What I have not understood are:

- the meaning of the symbol "@" in the variable expansion;
- if bitbake uses PYTHONPATH to search for the function, why did not pass the absolute path `${@bb.parse.__init__.vars_from_file(d.getVar('FILE', False),d)[0] or 'defaultpkgname'}`  instead of `"${@bb.parse.vars_from_file(d.getVar('FILE', False),d)[0] or 'defaultpkgname'}"`
- Is this type of variable expansion applied only in bitbake?. I searched in [gnu website](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), and there is not the application of "@" in the beginning of the structures.

Can someone help me understand them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @ symbol, is used bit bitbake for inline python variable expansion, and it basically states that you'd be calling a function and expanding its result, usually assigning it to a variable, in your case:

```
PN = "${@bb.parse.vars_from_file(d.getVar('FILE', False),d)[0] or 'defaultpkgname'}"
```

Its assigning to PN (package name) the result of the function vars_from_file coming from the bitbake python module parse, located at bitbake/lib/bb/parse/

Like any other Python module, it automatically loads **init**.py and has access to those functions when imported.

Whats special about these functions is that they've got access to bitbake's data dictionary, called "d".

AFAIC this IS specific to bitbake.